# how download gmail's attachments by linq and entityframework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, gmail

how can i download gmail's attachments by LINQ and entityframework?
mean is it possible?
where can i find it's provider?
would you please show us some codes?

Comment: not sure what you are asking. do you want something that logs into a gmail account and then downloads any attachment in any email?

Comment: yes, i want to show all of emails in that account in a grid and download all their attachments in my system by one shot.

Comment: Entity Framework is a database abstraction layer, or OR/M (object-relational mapper). It's not an abstraction layer against IMAP, which would be the preferred way to connect to a gmail account. What you want is an IMAP protocol implementation to search the mails for attachments and download them.

Comment: where can i find some samples about this protocol and using it?

Comment: LINQ and Entity Framework is not help for your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to start with.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/158549/Yet-Another-Email-Client-LINQ-to-IMAP

I have no experience with this though so can't comment on how good/bad it is. Nor do I know if it will work with Gmail. You will also probably need to enable IMap on your gmail account manually.

You can find out more about the IMAP protocol here
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol